# Where can I find an English or Hindi Translation of Agastya Ramayana?

Tags: ramayana, agastya

Is there a translation of Agastya Ramayana for free online?

Comment: I think it is only available in Tamil which can be found at: https://ia800905.us.archive.org/16/items/sreyas-old-ebooks/agasthya-ramayanam.pdf